# Having mapping issues when trying to save monolog logs into Elasticsearch use ElasticsearchHandler

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, monolog

I'm trying to start sending my logs into elastic search using monolog. (I'm using Symfony2).

I've set up monolog like this:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        elasticsearch:
            elasticsearch:
                host: %logger_elastic_host%
                port: %logger_elastic_port%
            type: elasticsearch
            level: info
```

It worked only few minutes until it broke with this error messages(a fatal error, I removed useless stuff):

> create: /monolog/logs/AVQKYsGRPmEhlo7mDfrN caused
>   MapperParsingException[failed to parse [context.stack.args]]; nested:
>   ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[unknown property [class]];

I've been looking with my collegue how to fix that. What we found out is:

- Elastic search receive the first logs and automatically build a mapping
- We send new logs with another mapping or slightly different to what was sent before and it breaks.
- In this case it's breaking here: context.stack.args.

The problem is that the context will always be very different.

What we would like is:

1. is anyone out there using Monolog to log to Elasticsearch
2. How do you guys manage to avoid this issue. (How can we manage to avoid it)?

thanks guys.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as you. Did you managed to fix it somehow? I will appreciate it :)

Comment: We did fix it, I left the company since then. I'm trying to contact the guy who implemented the fix.

Comment: Did you manage to contact the guy? :D

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because ES creates a mapping from the first document. If any document that is inserted after has the same property but with other type/format then ES will throw an error.

A solution is to create a custom monolog formatter and register it:

config.yml:

```
elasticsearch:
    type: elasticsearch
    elasticsearch:
        host: elasticsearch
    ignore_error: true
    formatter: my_elasticsearch_formatter
```

This line will make Monolog\Handler\ElasticSearchHandler ignore any other errors from Ruflin's Elastica package:

```
ignore_error: true
```

Then register a service with this name: my_elasticsearch_formatter:

```
    <service id="my_elasticsearch_formatter" class="AppBundle\Services\MyFormatter">
        <argument type="string">monolog</argument>
        <argument type="string">logs</argument>
    </service>
```

first argument is the index name, second arg is the type.

And the formatter class:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Services;

use function json_encode;
use Monolog\Formatter\ElasticaFormatter;
use function var_dump;

class MyFormatter extends ElasticaFormatter
{
    /**
     * @param string $index
     * @param string $type
     */
    public function __construct($index, $type)
    {
        parent::__construct($index, $type);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $record
     * @return array|\Elastica\Document|mixed|string
     */
    public function format(array $record)
    {
        $record['context'] = json_encode($record['context']);

        return parent::format($record);
    }
}
```

The downside of this solution is that it will json_encode the context. You will not be able to filter by inner properties of the context in ES but at least you will not lose important information about your logs.